# Django ManyToMany model: unable to access one relation from the other

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

My `models.py`:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Book", related_name="books", blank=True
    )

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

In `Django admin` I first created an instance of `Author`, without assigning him any `Book`:

[image]

Then I created a new `Book` and assigned *Leo Tolstoy* as  the`Author`:

[image]

In Django shell, I am able to access the `Book`'s `Author`:

```
>>> Book.objects.filter(title="War and Peace").first().author.first()
<Author: Leo Tolstoy>
```

But I'm unable to access the `Author`'s `Books`:

```
>>> Author.objects.filter(name="Leo Tolstoy").first().books.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

The book isn't assigned in the `Admin` view either:

[image]

I would like to access the `Author`'s `Books` as well as for the `Books`
to show in the `Author`'s `Admin` view.

Comment: You only need one `ManyToManyField`. Under the hood, DJango is creating two associative tables between the book and author tables. Changes to one table don't affect the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one `ManyToManyField`. You should also pass `"books"` as the `related_name` on `Book.authors` as this is the name Django will use for the many-to-many manager attribute it automatically adds to `Author` instances.

See the example in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships%5D) for more info.

When a `ManyToManyField` is created on both sides of a relation, Django is creating two associative tables between the book and author tables under the hood. Changes to one table don't affect the other.

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(
        Author, related_name="books", blank=True
    )
```

Comment: I've edited my `models.py` as per your example and now am able to access `Author`'s `Books` like this:
`>>> Author.objects.get(name="Leo Tolstoy").books.all() `

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
                
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name="books",blank=True)
```

You need **one** `ManyToManyField`, then django will create two associative tables between the `book` and `author` tables. Changes to one table will not affect the other. You can see in the django documentation about [many to many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). I have removed your `books` field in my answer because you have created an instance of your `Author` but you did not assign his 'book' and you have created a `Book` instance with giving `title` and `author` in your `Book` model. So  so that any of your data won't be deleted. I also added `related_name` to your `author` field in your `Book` model because when you try to get the **books** related to the **author** (for example "Loe Tolstoy") you can get by this:

```
Author.objects.get(name="Leo Tolstoy").books.all()
```